# Set a length that will adopt tikz's global lengths

Tags: tikz-pgf, lengths

I am trying to draw a rather simple tikz picture that consists of some very acurately defined levels. My code is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}

\newlength{\offset}
\setlength{\offset}{4.72983cm}

\begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm]
                %axis
                        \draw (-3,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (-3,20);
                %ticks
                        \foreach \y in {0,2,...,20}
                            \draw (-3,\y) -- (-3.25,\y) 
                            node[anchor=east] {\y};
                %labels      
                        \node[rotate=90, above=0.8cm] at (y axis mid) {\textbf{Energy[MeV]}};
                %input channel
                        \draw (-2,12.8435) -- (0,12.8435);
                        \node[above=0.2cm] at (-1,12.8435) {$p+{}^{19}F$};
                %compound nucleus
                        \draw[very thick] (2,20) -- (2,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,20);
                        \node[below=0.1cm] at (3.5,0) {${}^{20}Ne$};
                %output channel
                        \draw (7,\offset) -- (9,4.72983);%ground state
                        \draw (7,5.98765+\offset) -- (9,5.98765+4.72983);%1st state
        \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

As you can see I have set a length called `offset`. The problem is that at the present point the picture is rather big. What I want is to scale it only on `y axis`. If I change `\begin{tikzpicture}[y=1cm]` to `\begin{tikzpicture}[y=.6cm]` I get the ideal `y` dimension but the levels on the `output channel` are not set correctly.

Is there a way to define a length in `tikz` that will adapt tikz's lengths? What I mean is that by default tikz's length is `1cm`. When using `\draw (0,0) -- (0,1);` one does not specify that he's talking about cm. If the global length is changed(i.e. `[y=0.6]) the previous line will have 0.6 cm length. Is something like that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Remarks

Use a macro to store the pure value, such that `tikz` can scale it using it's own units.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{plotmarks}
\newcommand{\offset}{4.72983}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[y=0.2cm]
    %axis
    \draw (-3,0) -- coordinate (y axis mid) (-3,20);
    %ticks
    \foreach \y in {0,2,...,20}
    \draw (-3,\y) -- (-3.25,\y) 
    node[anchor=east] {\y};
    %labels      
    \node[rotate=90, above=0.8cm] at (y axis mid) {\textbf{Energy[MeV]}};
    %input channel
    \draw (-2,12.8435) -- (0,12.8435);
    \node[above=0.2cm] at (-1,12.8435) {$p+{}^{19}F$};
    %compound nucleus
    \draw[very thick] (2,20) -- (2,0) -- (5,0) -- (5,20);
    \node[below=0.1cm] at (3.5,0) {${}^{20}Ne$};
    %output channel
    \draw (7,\offset) -- (9,4.72983);%ground state
    \draw (7,5.98765+\offset) -- (9,5.98765+4.72983);%1st state
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! That was an interesting approach! Very clever! Thank's!!!